# Does Barbarian Rage stack with crit range improvements?

Tags: class-feature, barbarian, critical-hit, 13th-age

The Barbarian's Rage class feature allows the Barbarian to roll melee and thrown attack rolls as 2d20 instead of 1d20 and use the higher result, and in addition, get an extra crit if the higher result hits and both rolls are 11 or greater.

Does the latter bonus stack with improvements to crit range? Eg. if a barbarian has +1 crit range, will they be able to score a crit whenever rolling a hit with both dice coming up as 10 or greater?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### No

The rules have this to say about critical hits:

> **Crit Range**
>
> Crit range is what you must roll to score a crit. The standard crit range is a natural 20. Some powers and spells expand your crit range. Each point of improvement drops the number needed to score a critical hit by 1.

The feature Barbarian Rage provides you with an alternative way to score critical hits, rather than changing your base crit range. There's no reason to think further Crit Range improvements would modify Rage's mechanics.